# Time Expired error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My project was working perfectly; but it keeps giving me this error within this function: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.'

```
        public List<TransactionIssues> GetAllTransactions()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            List<TransactionIssues> transIssues = new List<TransactionIssues>();
            command.CommandText = "issue_sp_getallunpostedissues";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader rdrObj;



            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader();


                while (rdrObj.Read())
                {
                    TransactionIssues issues = new TransactionIssues();
                    issues.requisitionNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                    issues.transactionDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);
                    //issues.expense_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(2);
                    //issues.expense_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt16(3);
                    issues.inventory_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt32(2);
                    issues.inventory_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(3);
                    issues.docNumber = rdrObj.GetString(4);
                    issues.docType = rdrObj.GetString(5);
                    issues.items = getTransItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(4));
                    transIssues.Add(issues);
                }
                rdrObj.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: SqlConnection inherits from **IDisposable**, create instance of SqlConnection in using block. for example :
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString){}
This might helps

Comment: But i have that  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

Comment: When you create instance of SqlConnection in using block, it releases all its resources when scope of using block get finished.
That releases instance of connection available in connection pool as well, I am not 100% sure,but this may help

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar there's a `connection.Close();` in the `finally` block.

Comment: However note that both `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` also hold resources and should be closed. Using `using` is the cleanest way of accomplishing this.

Comment: sql reader was close; where should I close sqlcommand

Comment: I'm not seeing where I missed the closing

Comment: Not certain why it is happening now and it was ok before